# How do I make Invoke-RestMethod print the response body as is

Tags: json, rest, powershell-5.0

> Note: this question is here for historical reasons or for users of Powershell < 6.0.0. This problem should not occur in Powershell 6 and beyond.

I'm trying to use the powershell cmdlet `Invoke-RestMethod` to print a json endpoint to the console.

The command executes successfully but the end result is a terminal table containing all of the json's level 1 fields.

I'm running the cmdlet like this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri <some url here> -Method GET -ContentType "application/json"
```

And getting something like this:

```
sections _links
-------- ------
         {@{rel=parent; href=https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/templates/138...
```

How do I get it to just print the raw response to the terminal without formatting?

Comment: Have you piped this object into Get-Member?  If so, what are the results?  Chances are you'll need to simply call a method on the returned object to get the desired json result.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` is itended to provide you an object, instead of a simple json string. Try `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: @BryceMcDonald: No.

Comment: `$RestResponse | ConvertTo-Json`  PowerShell is being nice and forming the response into a `PSCustomObject`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, ok, I was missing that bit, thanks. so I guess this is pretty much the default in PS and in order to view the raw content I need to use `ConvertTo-Json`. thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, the `-Method` and `-ContentType` you are providing are the default, you can drop those. And to get the json, cast it back to json.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://example.com/" | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

I have no idea why you want to cast back to json, but well, here you go.

Comment: Note that the `-Depth` argument defaults to 2, and JSON fields any lower aren't handled correctly (in my case, string array entries were all concatenated into the same entry).  There is no warning emitted by this cmdlet when this occurs, so be sure to set the Depth to an appopriately large value for your data if you use ConvertTo-Json.

Answer (score 8):

The other answer works great for JSON responses, but the -UseBasicParsing switch works for any response type:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'http://example.com').Content
```

will give you just the response content (in the example.com case, the raw html, or in your use case, the raw JSON).

Comment: Note, this is deprecated since 6.0.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

Comment: What you mean is, this whole question and answer are not needed as of 6.0.0. I'll tag the question appropriately.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to _learn_ what's going on under the hood, i.e. what the answer raw data actually is. No matter deprecated or not.  Thanks.